# "ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized."

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# and currently I have some problems when I'm running this program without debugging.

This is the login page for my project. I've create a service-based database and I want to connect to the data which is username and password in the table 'Table' which is in the database.
However, I've encountered an issue which is "ExecuteScalar: Connection property has not been initialized." when I'm running this code.

Can anyone help me with this?

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\hp\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PersonalFinancialSoftware\PersonalFinancialSoftware\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Table where UserID = @userid AND Password = @password";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);
        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        conn.Open();
        string useridlogin = Convert.ToString(result);
        conn.Close();

        if (useridlogin != " ")
        {
            Home_Page homepage = new Home_Page();
            homepage.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID or password, please try again!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see that you've executed the ExecuteScalar method before opening the SQL Database connection, resulting in error you're getting.

Open the connection before ExecuteScalar method, and you're done.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\hp\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PersonalFinancialSoftware\PersonalFinancialSoftware\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();

    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Table where UserID = @userid AND Password = @password";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", textBox1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

    string useridlogin = Convert.ToString(result);
    conn.Close();

    if (useridlogin != " ")
    {
        Home_Page homepage = new Home_Page();
        homepage.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID or password, please try again!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have open connection after ExecuteScalar thats you are getting error, You must open connection befor ExecuteScalar try this code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=c:\users\hp\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\PersonalFinancialSoftware\PersonalFinancialSoftware\Login.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        conn.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM Table where UserID = @userid AND Password = @password";
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid", textBox1.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", textBox2.Text);
        object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

        string useridlogin = Convert.ToString(result);
        conn.Close();

        if (useridlogin != " ")
        {
            Home_Page homepage = new Home_Page();
            homepage.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid ID or password, please try again!", "Info", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
    }
```

In your code SQL query find connection. But you have open it after ExecuteScalar so this is giving you an error.